# AWS Glue Job fails with connection timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am new to AWS Glue. I have created a job that uses two Data Catalog tables and runs simple SparkSQL query on top of them. The job fails on the Transform step with Exception

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 [blah] failed: connect timed out;'
```

JDBC source (Redshift) VPC security group has both inbound and outbound rules configured.

I have seen another post on SO about configuring VPC endpoint for Glue itself, but I don't quite understand what it should look like? Should it be and interface to glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 or something else? I am confused.

UPD: Autogenerated pyspark script

```
## @params: [TempDir, JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "redshift_catalog", redshift_tmp_dir = TempDir, table_name = "analytics_mongo_raw_conversations", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0"]
## @return: DataSource0
## @inputs: []
DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "redshift_catalog", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], table_name = "analytics_mongo_raw_conversations", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "redshift_catalog", redshift_tmp_dir = TempDir, table_name = "analytics_mongo_raw_messages", transformation_ctx = "DataSource1"]
## @return: DataSource1
## @inputs: []
DataSource1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "redshift_catalog", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], table_name = "analytics_mongo_raw_messages", transformation_ctx = "DataSource1")
## @type: SqlCode
## @args: [sqlAliases = {"messages": DataSource1, "conversations": DataSource0}, sqlName = SqlQuery0, transformation_ctx = "Transform0"]
## @return: Transform0
## @inputs: [dfc = DataSource1,DataSource0]
Transform0 = sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query = SqlQuery0, mapping = {"messages": DataSource1, "conversations": DataSource0}, transformation_ctx = "Transform0")
job.commit()
```

Comment: I want to run complex SQL transformations, my impression was that Glue facilitates this by managing EMR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue, indeed there has to be a VPC endpoint.
In addition to that connection should use a private subnet with NAT gateway. My initial subnet didn't have NAT.

Example of the VPC endpoint configuration in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "glue" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  service_name      = var.glue_vpc_service_name
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"

  security_group_ids = var.security_group_ids 
  subnet_ids = var.subnet_ids

  tags = { mytag = "mytag"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [Glue Connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-using.html) so that you can connect to your Redshift Cluster. You have to make sure that this Glue Connection is placed in a private subnet.

Comment: I think I have defined one, using similar terraform code https://github.com/chgasparoto/terraform-aws-glue/blob/master/modules/glue_connection/main.tf. I don't think Crawler can run without this connection. Or there should be a different one?

Comment: What crawler are you talking about? And I don't use serverless, so I don't know if this is correct or not

Comment: The link you have shared in your reply is pointing to the Connection configuration for AWS Data Catalog. AWS uses this Connection to run Crawler to populate the data catalog. I am not connecting directly to the source from the script, I am using Data Catalog tables. I will update my question with autogenerate code.

Comment: Connections are for jobs as well. If you want to connect to Redshift you need to set up a connection like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-connections.html. If you already have a connection, you need to add it to your Glue Job. In addition you can test the connection in the AWS Glue Console, to see whether it works or not.

Comment: The issue is that I can see the connection attached to the job in the Jobs tab and when I test this connection the test passes, hence my confusion.
Since it already worked for Crawler service I have assumed that Job should work with this connection as well.